# How to convert the Android Java code to equivalent C# Xamarin android code

Tags: java, c#, android, .net, android-asynctask

Below given is my Android java code. I have an Interface **PermissionResultCallback**

```
public interface PermissionResultCallback {

    /**
     * Called with the permission result.
     *
     * @param enabled {@link true} if the permissions have been granted, otherwise {@code false}.
     */
    void onResult(boolean enabled);
}
```

I am calling this interface in **startWithPermissionPrompt** method

```
public void startWithPermissionPrompt(@Nullable final PermissionResultCallback callback) {
    requestPermissionsTask = new RequestPermissionsTask(context.getApplicationContext(), new PermissionResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(boolean enabled) {
            if (enabled) {
                //noinspection MissingPermission
                startAdapter();
            }

            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onResult(enabled);
            }
        }
    });

    requestPermissionsTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
}
```

The **RequestPermissionTask** is an Inner class which extends **AsyncTask**

```
private static class RequestPermissionsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private final Context context;
    private PermissionResultCallback callback;


    RequestPermissionsTask(Context context, PermissionResultCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... permissions) {
        int[] result = HelperActivity.requestPermissions(context, permissions);
        for (int element : result) {
            if (element == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Fortunately I have changed half of the equivalent code to C#. I know we can't change as exactly and directly to C#, but there may be some work arounds will be available. I have searched in all the forms but I can't able to find the exact solution.

Below I have added my Equivalent Xamarin android code for the above given Android java code.

**Interface PermissionResultCallback**

```
public interface IPermissionResultCallback
    {
        

        /**
         * Called with the permission result.
         *
         * @param enabled {@link true} if the permissions have been granted, otherwise {@code false}.
         */
        void onResult(Boolean enabled);
    }
```

**startWithPermissionPrompt** method

```
  public void StartWithPermissionPrompt(IPermissionResultCallback callback)
    {

        requestPermissionsTask = new RequestPermissionsTask(context, callback);


    }
```

here the problem is I can't able to implement the **onReceive** interface method from **IpermissionResultCallback** interface

**RequestPermissionsTask** inner class

```
public class RequestPermissionsTask 
    {


        public Context context;

        public IPermissionResultCallback permissionResultCallback;

        public RequestPermissionsTask(Context context, IPermissionResultCallback permissionResultCallback) 
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.permissionResultCallback = permissionResultCallback;

        }

        public async Task DoStuffInBackground()
        {
            
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int[] result = HelperActivity.RequestPermissions(context, permissions);

                
            foreach (var element in result)
                {
                    if (element == (int)Permission.Granted)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            });
        }

    }
```

In this inner class problem is I don't know how to pass params for **HelperActivity.RequestPermissions(context, permissions);** the permissions given here is automatically generated in android native code in doInBackground method.

I almost searched in all the forms and stackoverflow questions but I can't able to convert it.

Thanks in advance.